# Unique constraint calling user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, unique-constraint

I have two tables:

`create table primarytable
(
  value nvarchar(50) not null primary key
  type not null
)
create table secondarytable
(
  value nvarchar(50) not null,
  synonym nvarchar(50) not null,
  constraint pk_secondarytable primary key (value, synonym)
)`

So, there can be many synonyms for each value. What I want to do is to deny adding more synonyms if synonym+gettypeforvalue(value) is not unique.

So e.g.

```
primarytable:
-------------
value        | type
-------------|---------
Toyota F-150 | carmake
GMC Canyon   | carmake

secondarytable:
---------------
value        | synonym
-------------|---------------
Toyota F-150 | toyota pickup
GMC Canyon   | gmc pickup
```

is OK, but

```
primarytable:
-------------
value        | type
-------------|----------------
Toyota F-150 | carmake
GMC Canyon   | carmake

secondarytable:
---------------
value        | synonym
-------------|-----
Toyota F-150 | pickup
GMC Canyon   | pickup
```

should not be ok (synonym + value's associated type are not unique).

I tried making a function

```
create function uf_getTypeForValue(@value nvarchar(50))
    returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    return (select type from primarytable p where p.value = @value)
end
```

and then add a unique constraint to the secondarytable:

```
alter table secondarytable add constraint uc_secondarytable_synonym_unique_for_type
unique (synonym, uf_getTypeForValue(value))
```

However, I get error message on this `Incorrect syntax near '('.`

I have sucessfully called functions from `check`-constraints before, so apparently I can't do so with unique constraints?

Is there simply a syntax trick I need to know or how can I accomplish this another way?

Answer (score 1):

From the syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx), I think you can only do columns for a unique constraint. However, I see that the "[CHECK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx#Check)" constraint can contain a logical expression. So you could use that to accomplish it. Make your row count query inside the function like so:

```
--drop function NumberOfSimilarRows
CREATE FUNCTION NumberOfSimilarRows(@synonymToCheck nvarchar(50), @valueToCheck nvarchar(50))
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @rowcount int
   SELECT @rowcount = COUNT(*) FROM secondarytable WHERE synonym = @synonymToCheck and value = dbo.uf_getTypeForValue(@valueToCheck)
   RETURN @rowcount
END;
```

Then you can use it in a CHECK constraint like so:

```
ALTER TABLE secondarytable
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_secondarytable_synonym_unique_for_type 
CHECK (dbo.NumberOfSimilarRows(synonym, value) <= 1 );
```

Comment: It could also be checked through a trigger...not sure which is better.